# modelname.objects.all() displays error

Tags: python, django, database

I get an error whenever i try to access the data from database in the program.

This is models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Files(models.Model):
    serno=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    secondfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstfile +' '+ self.secondfile
```

This is views.py

```
from .models import Files
def getfile(request):
    data=Files.objects.all()
    return data
```

This displays an error at objects in "Files.objects.all()"
The error is

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Files'  
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items
```

If I ignored that warning and continued with my program, the following happened
Consider an example program

example.py

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='website.settings'
import django
django.setup()
from plagiarism_check.views import getfile
dbf1=getfile
print(dbf1)
```

I expect an output of the data in the database table "Files". But instead I get something like this

```
<function getfile at 0x0000000003DF1D08>
```

PS: I've tried to print Files.objects.all() in powershell and it worked. But I want to access them in my example.py

Comment: Your code is fine, you can ignore the warning from PyCharm.

Comment: Please check the updates question too. Thanks

Comment: You need to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and call `django.setup()` in your script. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#either-configure-or-django-settings-module-is-required) for more info.

Comment: Should I set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and call django.setup()  in views.py?

Comment: No, as I said, you should do it in your standalone script. You don't need to do it in your views.

Comment: I still get errors. I updated my example.py as you said

Comment: What is your `settings.py`? Unless it's `mysite/settings.py`, the line `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='mysite.settings'` looks incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for saying. I made the changes in example.py , but the output is not as expected. See the updated question.

Comment: Remember `getfile` is not the same as `getfile()`. We've gone really far off topic, that has nothing to do with your original question. I can't help you debug your script any further.

Comment: Yeah. Got the output. Thanks for your help :)